# Как отключить панель networks Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, powershell, azure

подскажите каким образом можно отключить Вот это окно Сети, через Azure powershell script
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В логике администрирования этот параметр следует установить заранее, чтобы этот вопрос решал не пользователь. Значит нужно настроить обнаружение сети для всех профилей заранее, например через утилиту [netsh](https://dwaves.de/2014/12/10/windows-7-8-turn-network-discovery-on-or-off-in-command-prompt/), либо через локальную политику, спрятав некоторые [элементы](https://dwaves.de/2014/12/10/windows-7-8-turn-network-discovery-on-or-off-in-command-prompt/) Панели управления от пользователя.

Comment: `powershell Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private` не оно?